# Is it possible to get an instance of every class that inherits from an interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance, instance

I have a small project that I'm making, and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to get an instance of every class that inherits from a particular interface.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
public interface IExample
{
    string Foo();
}

public class Example1 : IExample
{
    public string Foo()
    {
        return "I came from Example1 !";
    }
}

public class Example2 : IExample
{
    public string Foo()
    {
        return "I came from Example2 !";
    }
}

//Many more ExampleN's go here

public class ExampleProgram
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var examples = GetExamples();

        foreach (var example in examples)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(example.Foo());
        }
    }

    public static List<IExample> GetExamples()
    {
        //What goes here?
    }
}
```

Is there any way (short of hard-coding it) for the GetExamples method to return a list containing an instance of each class inheriting from the interface IExample? Any insight you can give would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [Check if a class is derived from a generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/c-reflection-check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class)

Also: [Implementations of interface through Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80247/implementations-of-interface-through-reflection) (**this may be exactly what you want**)

You will basically just need to enumerate through every type in the target assembly and test to see if it implements the interface.

Comment: That second links answers your question, but it (obviously) only knows about types of assemblies you have loaded.  So if you are making a library type class, you may not know about everything that implements your interface.

Comment: The second link was what I was looking for in terms of finding the types that implement that interface. The latter half of Matt Kellogg's answer below demonstrates how the objects would then be created. I wish I could mark both answers as correct :P

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Building upon Matt's solution, I would implement it something like this:

```
public static List<IExample> GetExamples()
{
    return GetInstances<IExample>().ToList();
}

private static IEnumerable<T> GetInstances<T>()
{
    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .Where(type => type.IsClass &&
                       !type.IsAbstract &&
                       type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null &&
                       typeof (T).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        .Select(type => (T) Activator.CreateInstance(type));
}
```

This solution skips types that cannot be instantiated such as abstract classes, derived interfaces and classes without default (parameterless) public constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use reflection.

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` should be your starting point.

EDIT: Code that should help

```
Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
foreach(Type tp in types)
{
    if (typeof(IExample).IsAssignableFrom(tp))
    {
        if (tp.IsInterface == false)
        {
            IExample t = Activator.CreateInstance(tp) as IExample;
            Console.WriteLine(t.Foo());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do something like that:

```
    public static List<IExample> GetExamples()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IExample))).ToList();

        List<IExample> returnMe = new List<IExample>();
        foreach (var type in types)
            returnMe.Add((IExample) Activator.CreateInstance(type));

        return returnMe;
    }
```

Comment: routeNpingme responded first with how to get the types that inherit from a given interface, but you demonstrated how to then return concrete instances of those types. I wish I could mark both answers as correct :P Thanks for the help!