# Using reflection to find interfaces implemented

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have the following case:

```
public interface IPerson { .. }    
public class Person : IPerson { .. }    
public class User : Person { .. }
```

Now; if I have a "User" object - how can I check if this implements IPerson using reflection? To be more precise I have an object that might have a property SomeUser, which should be of some type implementing the interface "IPerson". In my case I actually have a User, but this is what I want to check through reflection. I can't figure out how to check the property type since it is a "User", but I want to check if it implements IPerson...:

```
var control = _container.Resolve(objType); // objType is User here
var prop = viewType.GetProperty("SomeUser");
if ((prop != null) && (prop.PropertyType is IPerson)) 
{ .. }
```

*(Note that this is a simplification of my actual case, but the point should be the same...)*

Comment: If you already have an object instance you do not need reflection to check whether your object implements a certain interface. You can simply check `if (objUser is IPerson)`

Comment: Isn't 0xA3's comment the correct answer?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check the [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28VS.80%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 20):

```
var control = _container.Resolve(objType); 
var prop = viewType.GetProperty("SomeUser");
if ((prop != null) && (prop.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IPerson))) 
{ .. }
```

Comment: Thanks, but think I'll go with Type.IsAssignableFrom.

Comment: Type.IsAssignableFrom actually came back false in a LINQ expression where it should have been true.  This Type.GetInterfaces().Contains([Interface Type]) worked.

Answer (score 0):

See [Implementations of interface through Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80247/implementations-of-interface-through-reflection).