# C# How to determine if a type implements a given interface?

Tags: .net, inheritance, reflection

I want the following to return `true`:

```
var isIt = IsDisposable(typeof(TextWriter));
```

where:

```
bool IsIDisposable(Type t){
    ??? 
    // I tried:
    //return t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IDisposable)); //returns false
    // the other t.IsXXX methods don't fit the requirement as far as I can tell
}
```

Comment: Use reflection. Does this SO article help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519530/using-reflection-to-find-interfaces-implemented

Comment: Would a check of "t as/is IDisposable" do the trick?

Comment: @Anthony I don't have an instance of a type, but a type. Can't use `is` on that (I mean I can, but it won't work as expected)

Comment: Of course. I deleted my comment as it became more evident you were actually working with the type.

Comment: @RvdK Same comment as for Anthony. I don't work on an instance of some type, but on a `Type`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a type implements an interface with C# reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963160/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-an-interface-with-c-sharp-reflection)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
bool IsDisposable = typeof(IDisposable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TextWriter));
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/DDy3G8)

Comment: no you can't. `IsAssignableFrom` works *the other way around*: BaseType.IsAssignableFrom(Derived) returns true.

Comment: Ok, that works :) Actually, it's conceivably faster than `GetInterfaces()`.Upvoted

Comment: I had made a demo on ideone too, to prove it doesn't work :) (before reading your updated answer)

Comment: @Christi: Yes, i've updated my answer after one minute but before you've posted your comment. I find the correct order in `IsAssignableFrom` hard to remember.

Comment: The seemingly backwards semantics of `IsAssignableFrom()` made me miss it when searching for the solution on my own. It would be better, IMO, if there was a `Type.IsAssignableTo(Type)` method instead (or in addition to...)

Answer (score 6):

I found it: [Type.GetInterfaces()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is what I need:

```
bool IsIDisposable(Type t){
    return t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IDisposable));
}
```

From the documentation, `Type.GetInterfaces()` returns:

> Type: System.Type[]
>   An array of Type objects representing all the
>   interfaces implemented **or inherited** by the current Type.

Comment: Will this work even if you implemented say `IFoo` which in-turn implements `IDisposable`?