# Return the types of interfaces that a class implements C#

Tags: c#, class, interface

Is there a way to get the type of an interface that a class implements. For further explanation of the problem here's what I mean. For example:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{

}

public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{

}

public class SecondClass
{

    ISomeInterface someclass;

    public SecondClass()
    {
        someclass = new SomeClass();
    }

    public Type GetInterfaceInSomeWay()
    {
        //some code
    }

}
```

I need to fill the commented area. Thanks in advance for your help, community!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface-with-c-sharp-3-0

Comment: @FSou1 I think this question is asking the exact opposite of that question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using reflection to find interfaces implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519530/using-reflection-to-find-interfaces-implemented)

Comment: Not a duplicate - I did see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx) though

Comment: @Sayse, how is this different from the question I linked?

Comment: The type *could* implement multiple interfaces. If you only expect the class to implement `ISomeInterface` then in order to obtain an instance of `Type` you could merely use `typeof(ISomeInterface)`.

Comment: @Yossarian - I meant of FSou1's link, my comments didn't update before I posted

Comment: @Sayse, oh, ok, sorry then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`typeof(SomeClass).GetInterfaces()`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Type tinterface in typeof(SomeClass).GetInterfaces())
{
   Console.WriteLine(tinterface.ToString());
}
```