# .NET - Getting all implementations of a generic interface?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, interface

An answer on " [Implementations of interface through Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80247/implementations-of-interface-through-reflection) " shows how to get all implementations of an interface. However, given a generic interface, `IInterface<T>`, the following doesn't work:

```
var types = TypesImplementingInterface(typeof(IInterface<>))
```

Can anyone explain how I can modify that method?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
public static bool DoesTypeSupportInterface(Type type, Type inter)
{
    if(inter.IsAssignableFrom(type))
        return true;
    if(type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == inter))
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static IEnumerable<Type> TypesImplementingInterface(Type desiredType)
{
    return AppDomain
        .CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
        .Where(type => DoesTypeSupportInterface(type, desiredType));

}
```

It can throw a `TypeLoadException` though but that's a problem already present in the original code. For example in LINQPad it doesn't work because some libraries can't be loaded.

Comment: Is there a way around the TypeLoader exception?

Comment: You can try catching it. But when I tried that linqpad crashed.

Comment: `GetInterfaces()` doesn't return interfaces implemented by a parent class, does it? Do I need to recursively look at parent classes until I hit `typeof(System.Object)`?

Comment: @DavidPfeffer It includes inherited interfaces:  `GetInterfaces()` returns "all the interfaces implemented or inherited by the current Type."

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `IInterface<object>` (using `System.Object` for T as an example) doesn't inherit from the "open" generic type `IInterface<>`. A "closed" generic type is a root type, just like `IFoo`. You can only search for closed generic types, not open ones, meaning you could find everything that inherits from `IInterface<int>`. `IFoo` does not have a base class, nor does `IInterface<object>` or `IInterface<string>` etc.