# Find all types implementing a certain generic interface with specific T type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have several classes inheriting from `abstract class BrowsingGoal`. Some of these implement an interface called `ICanHandleIntent<TPageIntent> where TPageIntent: PageIntent`.

To give a concrete example:

```
public class Authenticate : BrowsingGoal, ICanHandleIntent<AuthenticationNeededIntent>
{
    ...
}
```

Now I would like to scan the CurrentDomain's assemblies for all types implementing the `ICanHandleIntent` with the `AuthenticationNeededIntent`. This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to find anything:

```
protected BrowsingGoal FindNextGoal(PageIntent intent)
{
    // Find a goal that implements an ICanHandleIntent<specific PageIntent>
    var goalHandler = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
        .FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsAssignableFrom((typeof (BrowsingGoal))) &&
                                t.GetInterfaces().Any(x =>
                                    x.IsGenericType &&
                                    x.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (ICanHandleIntent<>)) &&
                                    x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == intent.GetType()));

    if (goalHandler != null)
        return Activator.CreateInstance(goalHandler) as BrowsingGoal;
}
```

Some help would be very appreciated!

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault`

Remove that as it only analyzes the first type. Replace it by `.Where`. If you only want the first result, add a `FirstOrDefault()` at the end of the statement.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Not true, `FirstOrDefault()`, when provided with a predicate parameter, loops through the collection and returns the first instance that evaluates to true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This condition is incorrect:

```
x.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ICanHandleIntent<>))
```

a type implementing an instance of a generic interface is not assignable from the generic interface definition itself, which `ICanHandleIntent<>` represents.

What you want instead is

```
x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICanHandleIntent<>)
```

The check for the type parameter is also wrong. It should be

```
x.GetGenericArguments()[0] == intent.GetType()
```

because you are looking for the type argument, i.e. the type in triangular brackets following the generic name.