# .NET Core: Identify All Classes that Inherit from Generic Base Class

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I would like to iterate all classes that derive from a generic base class. My problem is that I do not know how (if it is possible) to get the generic base class as a Type.

I can do:

```
Type myGeneric = typeof(MyGeneric<MyConcreteA,MyConcreteB>);
```

I cannot do:

```
Type myGeneric = typeof(MyGeneric<TMyA,TMyB>));
```

Is something like this possible?

```
foreach (Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    foreach (Type type in asm.GetTypes().Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract))
    {
        if (type.IsSubclassOf(myGeneric))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all types implementing specific open generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645430/get-all-types-implementing-specific-open-generic-type)

Comment: Thank you! I am hoping that this is the clue: Type t = typeof(IWhatever<>); which seems to compile for an interface but maybe not a concrete type. Maybe I need to refactor to an interface.

Comment: Actually, I can't seem to do typoof(IWhatever<>) either. So I am not sure whether this is an answer.

Comment: `typeof(x<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition();`

Comment: But implementing a non-generic interface is the simplest solution.

Comment: Ah, just noticed that you have two generic parameters, you still need the comma in the parameter list `typeof(MyGeneric<,>)`