# How can I find non-generic interfaces that derive from a generic one?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

```
public interface IEntity<T> {}
public interface IUserEntity:IEntity<User> {}
public class UserEntity: IUserEntity{}
```

So my question is: how can I find all the 'IUserEntity'-like interfaces, as well as all the 'UserEntity'-like implementations inside an assembly?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I think this might help you along: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8645430/10608418

Comment: After hours researching and experimenting, I modified the original answer from the linked post to something more intuitive, to me at least:)

Comment: Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IEntity<>)).GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(
                    i => i.IsGenericType &&
                    i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntity<>))).ToList();