# How to limit a generic class to certain types (including native data types)

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create a generic structure (an array basically) and restrict the possible types to types of ISerializable and a bunch of native data types like int,uint,float,double,char etc. The problem is that I cannot mark these native data types with an interface and my researches stated that it is not possible to use something like an **or** keyword in generic type constraint construction (where clause). So the question is how can I realize that?

If you are interested in context: I have a BinaryStream class responsible for reading and writing from/to a stream. The **custom** ISerializable interface has function `void Serialize(BinaryStream f)` that either reads or write from/to stream f (depends on state in f). Actually written or read are of course native data types that the structs are made of. These are read or written via `f.Transfer(ref data)`. Using a standard BinarySerializer from the .NET framework is not an option, because it has to be done in a custom way.

```
public class AutoArray<T> : ISerializable where T : ISerializable //or int or uint or float etc.
{
    private uint n;
    private T[] data;

    public void Serialize(BinaryStream f)
    {
        f.Transfer(ref n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (data[i] is ISerializable) data[i].Serialize(f);
            else f.Transfer(ref data[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your researches have yielded to you the correct information - .NET does not allow you to restrict generics to some abstract numeric data type, because they(numeric datatypes) do not have any common interface. That's a shame and sometimes a problem, but the fact nonetheless.

If you really have very generic code that could work with numeric types then you could try to implement your class in C++\CLI - it is C++, so it allows you to use templates, and it is .NET language that supports generics:

```
// C# - use base interface for your serializer, define it in separate assembly(or directly in C++\CLI)
public interface IMySerializer<T> {...}

// C++\CLI - add the reference to the project with IMySerializer<T>
template<class Type>
public ref abstract class MyNumericSerializerBase : IMySerializer<Type> {...};

// C++\CLI - you can't use template class in C# - it must be specialized
public ref class MyIntSerializer : MyNumericSerializerBase<Int32> {...};
```

Then you add the created C++\CLI dll as reference to your project. Well, you will still have to create such `MyIntSerializer` for each of the numeric types, but at least you won't have to replicate all the code. And to effectively get the needed `IMySerializer<T>` you can use some factory that searches for specific `IMySerializer<T>` through reflection either by attributes or through [IsAssignableFrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849210/net-getting-all-implementations-of-a-generic-interface):

```
// C#
public class MySerializerFactory
{
    public IMySerializer<T> GetSerializer<T>() {...}
}
```

It is not the simplest solution, but I used when I needed to create types that differ only by numeric types in calculations.

**EDIT:**

Could it be an overkill to use C++\CLI? Well, for simple cases it is not very difficult to apply, but if you won't use anything like

```
template<class Type>
public ref abstract class MyNumericSerializerBase : IMySerializer<Type> 
{ 
public:
    Type  GetValue(Type first, Type second)
    {
        return first + (second / 2); // The REAL advantage(and potential problems source) of C++\CLI templates
    }
 }
```

then there are no real advantages in such a method, except the avoidance of code duplication. And, taking into account that there are few numeric types you could just implement your specific serializers in C#:

```
// C#
public class MyInt32Serializer: IMySerializer<Int32> {...}
```

and use the same factory (or locator) pattern:

```
// C#
public class MySerializerFactory
{
    public IMySerializer<T> GetSerializer<T>() {...}
}
```

Concrete implementers could be found like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849210/net-getting-all-implementations-of-a-generic-interface)

Comment: Well I would like to avoid to create a new dll because of such a minor feature. To use another language also seems pretty 'messy'. I already am using unsafe functions though, if this helps ^^

Comment: The closed generic/factory pattern is what C# is encouraging you to do here.

Answer (score -1):

This is a tremendously messy implementation, but what would you think of leaving the generic type unconstrained and checking it in the constructor? Basically have it throw a NotImplementedException if type T isn't on your whitelist of allowed types.

Comment: Yeah, I also considered that and it is a possible solution with the disadvantage of losing compile time error detection. You say it is super messy. I am also open for a better implementation. So if you or someone can enlighten me :)

Comment: Sorry, clarification: I meant my proposed solution was messy.  I didn't mean to impugn your solution/attempt.