# Ninject - How to implement Command Pattern with Ninject?

Tags: c#, command, ninject

Currently, I'm implementing the command pattern with ninject doing the following bindings:

```
kernel.Bind<ICommand<InsertParams>>().To<InsertProductCommand>();
kernel.Bind<ICommand<UpdateParams>>().To<UpdateProductCommand>();
kernel.Bind<ICommand<DeleteParams>>().To<DeleteProductCommand>();
```

My question is: these definitions and commands can grow over the time. Is there any way to reduce all these bindings to something like 'Bind(typeof(ICommand<>))' so that every interface depending on the generic type is resolved appropriately?

Ex: If I implement a "ValidateProductCommand" which implements "ICommand" the binding is automatically resolved without adding an extra binding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there's [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions) which can help you with that.
And then it's quite easy to do:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom(typeof(ICommand<>))
    .BindSingleInterface());
```

---

Full test code (using Ninject, Ninject.Extensions.Conventions, xUnit and FluentAssertions nuget packages):

```
using FluentAssertions;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;
using Xunit;

namespace NinjectTest.ClosedGenericConvention
{
    public interface ICommand<TParam> { }

    public class FloatCommand : ICommand<float> { }

    public class IntCommand : ICommand<int> { }

    public class Test
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Fact()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();

            kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .InheritedFrom(typeof(ICommand<>))
                .BindSingleInterface());

            kernel.Get<ICommand<float>>().Should().BeOfType<FloatCommand>();
            kernel.Get<ICommand<int>>().Should().BeOfType<IntCommand>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked wonders to my problem! Now every class gets the implementation I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from your question whether `ICommand<T>` is your own interface or if you're using WPF.  If it's yours you can create a non-generic `ICommand` interface and have `ICommand<T>` descend from it.  This would get you to:

```
kernel.Bind<ICommand>().To<InsertProductCommand>();
kernel.Bind<ICommand>().To<UpdateProductCommand>();
kernel.Bind<ICommand>().To<DeleteProductCommand>();
```

Then you can use reflection to locate classes that implement `ICommand` and bind them.

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(p));

foreach (var type in types) {
    kernel.Bind<ICommand>().To(type);
}
```

Even if you can't make `ICommand<T>` descend from `ICommand`, you can still get it done w/reflection.  It's just a little more complicated.  My suggestion above borrows from (1) below but (2) shows how to adjust for `ICommand<T>` directly.

1. [Getting all types that implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface)
2. [.NET - Getting all implementations of a generic interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849210/net-getting-all-implementations-of-a-generic-interface)

Also you might consider creating a `CommandModule : NinjectModule` to keep the reflection-related bindings away from the rest of your registrations.

Comment: It's a custom ICommand. But binding the same interface ICommand to multiple binds wouldn't it lead to a multiple bindings error?