# Is this the right way to use the Command Pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, command-pattern

Related to this other question: [**How to inject an action into a command using Ninject?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035014/how-to-inject-an-action-into-a-command-using-ninject?noredirect=1#comment46313497_29035014)

Based on the comments on the above-referenced question, I take it that I would just need to create some command classes and inject them in my view model so that the view's controls just need to bind to them. I conceptually agree and understand the benefits. Besides, I wish to be as clean as possible using Ninject, DI and Constructor Injection.

Following these important rules, here's what I've come with so far.

**CreateCategoryCommand**

```
public class CreateCategoryCommand : ICommand {
    public CreateCategoryCommand(CreateCategoryView view) {
        if(view == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("view");
        this.view = view;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return true; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter) { view.Show(); }

    private readonly CreateCategoryView view;
}
```

**CategoriesManagementViewModel**

```
public class CategoriesManagementViewModel {
    public CategoriesManagementViewModel(ICommand createCommand) {
        if (createCommand == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("createCommand");
        this.createCommand = createCommand;
    }

    public ICommand CreateCommand { get { return createCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand createCommand;
}
```

So now when the **CategoriesManagementView** is initialized, it is constructor-injected with the **CategoriesManagementViewModel**, which in turn is constructor-injected with the **CreateCategoryCommand**, which in turn is constructor-injected with the **CreateCategoryView**, so no redundant dependency, neither any cycle-dependency.

Now, when I the **CategoriesManagementView.CreateButton**, it shall trigger the bound **CategoriesManagementViewModel.CreateCommand**, which will show the **CreateCategoryView** to the user, and this view shall have its own proper commands as well injected the same way.

Finally, this would render the **RelayCommand** class as useless...

Is that it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I agree that `RelayCommand` and `DelegateCommand` and the like are ways of implementing commands that violate SOLID principles, so your solution here to replace them with a separate class is the correct one.  Doing so also keeps your ViewModels much cleaner.

That said, you're violating MVVM pretty badly by having a class in your ViewModels layer (the `CreateCategoryCommand`) have knowledge of a concrete that is in your Views layer (`CreateCategoryView`).  Nothing in your ViewModels layer should have a direct reference to anything in your Views layer.

Imagine it this way - you've separated your layers out into different dlls - Views.dll, ViewModels.dll, Models.dll, DataLayer.dll.  If something in your ViewModels has a reference to a concrete in your Views, and obviously your Views will have a reference to ViewModels (as is necessary), then you have a circular reference problem.

The solution is to have your View object implement an interface (Interface Segregation Principle) like `IDialog` or `IUiDisplay` (choose the name depending on how abstract you want to be), and have your command have a dependency on that interface, NOT the direct concrete type, like so:

In Views:

```
public class CreateCategoryView : ..., IUiDisplay
{
    ...
}
```

In ViewModels:

```
public interface IUiDisplay
{
    void Show();
}

public class CreateCategoryCommand : ICommand 
{
    public CreateCategoryCommand(IUiDisplay uiDisplay) {
        if(display == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("uiDisplay");
        this.display = uiDisplay;
    }

    private readonly IUiDisplay display;
    ...
}
```

Now, your Command no longer has a direct dependency on a concrete (so it is now mockable and testable!) from a higher layer.  Now you can have your DI/IOC resolve the command dependency to the specific view class you want to inject. (I'd personally inject a view factory into the command instead, and only create the view lazily, but that's a different discussion).

One related note - if you implement commands by directly having them implement `ICommand`, then you're going to repeat yourself a lot (DRY).  My suggestion is to create an abstract base class (`CommandBase` or something) that implements the requirements of `ICommand`.  You'll find that all your commands that derive from it will only override `Execute()` and sometimes `CanExecute()`.  This saves you from having to implement the event (and code to raise the event) in every command, and in many cases saves you from having to implement `CanExecute` since most commands just return `true`.

Comment: Now you talk! This is the kind of answer I was awaiting! I agree that I violated ISP and SOLID by injecting a concrete view class. My point was to make it clear what was in there practically. In the end, I would have ended with something similar to what you propose, since all my views have an IMyView, and I work with them quite exclusively. Besides, your explanation is really clear and no room for ambiguity is left. That's what I call a complete answer. My sincerest thanks! +1